# Access 2016 DB does not seem to connect correctly

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I'm new to c# and im trying to make a store bill generator for fun and learning. Since I don't know much about databases Access seemed decently simple.
I'm just trying to give user confirmation that the connection to the db is successful, I've connected the db to my project but when I run the program nothing happens

I've tried giving the status in a label but it doesn't show either.
availableproductsbox is a listbox

```
    private void availableproductsbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\admin\source\repos\MultiCashTrack\MultiCashTrack\items.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
            connection.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Database connected");
            connection.Close();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Database connection failed"+ ex);
        }

    }
```

I expect it to show a message box showing "Database connected" but it doesn't show

Comment: I didn't understand number 1), and there is no exception

Comment: Corrected my comment: If it doesn't show, that suggests 1 of 2 things has happened: 1) The `connection.Open();` never completes, or 2) An exception is thrown. Are you seeing an exception?

Comment: What is your exception here   @flexy

Comment: I am not getting any that's why i'm confused, I guess i'll look into 1

Comment: Could you try to MessageBox.Show("Something") at the very beginning of your code? Have you ever seen this message box in your environement?

Comment: it shows if I put in the the main method without connecting to db.
Also flxed it by removing the "Persist Security Info=False"
Maybe I was using outdated parameters or something